# Visual Code C++ No such file or directory

Tags: g++, visual-studio-code

Thank you for reading my question. I have just started to use Visual Code currently running version 1.4. 
I am using it for C++ and using mingw (g++) for compilation. I created a simple "hello world" example. But I am not able to compile the code. 
There is not lot of help available on the internet. I went throught he documentation of c++ extension but no help.

I am getting following error:
"g++: error: Makefile: No such file or directory"

Here is how the tasks.json looks:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "g++",
"isShellCommand": true,
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "Makefile",
        // Make this the default build command.
        "isBuildCommand": true,
        // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
        "showOutput": "always",
        // No args
        "args": ["all"],

        // Use the standard less compilation problem matcher.
        "problemMatcher": {
            "owner": "cpp",
            "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
            "pattern": {
                "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                "file": 1,
                "line": 2,
                "column": 3,
                "severity": 4,
                "message": 5
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Here is how Launch.Json looks

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "C++ Launch (GDB)",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "launchOptionType": "Local",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:/mingw64/bin/",
        "targetArchitecture": "x64",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.cpp",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "environment": []
    },
    {
        "name": "C++ Attach (GDB)",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "launchOptionType": "Local",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:/mingw64/bin/",
        "targetArchitecture": "x64",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.cpp",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "environment": [],
        "processId": "enter program's process ID"
    }
]
```

}

I also get following error:
spawn C:/Users/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-0.5.0/debugAdapters/OpenDebugAD7 ENOENT. Stopping the debug adapter.

Please let me know if you guys have an idea about what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.
Avi

Answer (score 0):

There should be a makefile for your project to compile.

Try creating a simple makefile in your projects root directory

sample makefile:

`all:
    g++ main.cpp -o main.exe`

run `make all` to compile or use Tasks:Run Task - Makefile

The `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.cpp"` in launch.json should point to the compiled output `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.exe"` and `"miDebuggerPath": "C:/mingw64/bin/",` should be `"miDebuggerPath": "C:/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe"` in here.